# Install python2 pandas module on Arch Linux (ARM)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, archlinux

Is it possible to get the python (2.7) pandas module working and a Arch Linux that uses ARM?

I tried:

```
pip2 install pandas
```

but no luck..

I tried downloading the [AUR tar ball](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python2-pandas/?ID=46552&comments=all)

but it complains about ARM

BTW: I'm not much of an Linux expert...

### UPDATE

I finally got the time (Christmas is a very busy time) to record the install message:
[image: 1st part]
[image: 2nd part]
and then it just stall here..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an ARM device to test on (I am however, running Arch Linux).

Based on my investigation...

`pandas` requires `numpy`. Based on [this issue request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2290#issuecomment-9623172), I suspect that `numpy` itself works on ARM processors; provided of course, that you have the tools to install the package (e.g. gcc).

However, I suspect that `pandas` has not been developed to work on the ARM architecture (given that I have no problems installing it on an x86-64 architecture).

Comment: I have installed numpy on it.. Think I just used "pacman -S python2-numpy" to get it. Are there any work arounds to get pandas??

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` do not seem to be available on ARM. See the [package search](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=python2-numpy).

Also, I think a [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_Helpers) could help you find missing dependencies needed to build and install a AUR pakage.

Comment: I have installed numpy on it.. Think I just used "pacman -S python2-numpy" to get it

Comment: As I do not have a ARM device, I can not say. What is your exact error while installing with pip ?

Comment: Ghislain Hivon - sorry for the waiting time, but I finally got a print out of the message.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy and Pandas are compiled for Arch Linux on ARMv7h and available [here](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages).

However, those seems to only be compiled for Python3.
I've found Python2.7 wheels available on [piwheels](https://www.piwheels.org/simple/scipy/).

`pandas-0.24.2-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl` from piwheels should work once you also install compatible dependencies (pytz and dateutil).

I do know and have tested the packages [here](https://github.com/earlvanze/armv7h-packages), and I'll continue to add more as I test them.

To install, simply untar the `.xz` packages like this and they'll automatically end up in the correct directory:

```
tar -xf {tar package} -C /
```

For the wheels, do this:

```
unzip {wheel.whl} -d /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

For `six.py` just move/copy:

```
cp six.py /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py
```